# ASMx86 CMP instruction flags

Tags: assembly

I have some decompiled assembly:

```
cmp     byte ptr [esi+esi*4-7D7A6FF5h], 0Bh
sal     byte ptr [ecx+ecx*4], 0Bh
sal     byte ptr [ecx+ecx*4], 0Bh
loopne  loc_BC58F56
xchg    eax, edi
or      esp, eax
mov     al, byte_F8F80B97
```

I am trying to understand the CMP flag operations.

1. what code happens if CMP is resolved to 0?
2. what code happens if CMP is not resolved to 0?

I am assuming both SAL instructions are executed and cmp flag resolved to 0 then loopNE takes action

if it matters i see this on top:

```
_GameWorld:0BC58F84 _gameworld_MoveMode___vftable_:         ; DATA XREF: _GameWorld:0B826688o
_GameWorld:0BC58F84                                         ; _GameWorld:0B826712o ...
```

Comment: The result of the `CMP` is ignored because `SAL` overwrites the flags. That doesn't look like valid code, the `or esp, eax` is very strange. I'd say you disassembled wrong, or even disassembled data.

Comment: Any chances that it could it be an empty if statement? also please post as an answer, i think you answered me :) @Jester

Comment: Also i disassembled a DMP file from procdump.exe

Comment: Not all of the dump is code, have you made sure you disassembled code?

Comment: @Jester i think so. How can make sure? i am using IDA pro. i see DATA XREF on top area. Does this mean this is data?

Comment: That's data not code, the label clearly says "table".

Comment: haha, thanks i was in the wrong section of the decompile :P i found what i was looking for now THANK YOU!